# New image resolution problem in Blogger site

Tags: image, blogger, image-compression

I'm having a problem with image resolution when uploaded to my blogger site: its resolution is decreased dramatically, looking blurry and compressed.

This is the original image:

[image]

and this is what it looks like after upload:

[image]

The available image size options "Small', "Medium", "large". "X-Large", "Original size" do not fix the problem. If the last option is used, the image gets so big that it goes outside of the template. If original image size is reduced before uploading, its resolution is decreased after upload. Been using Blogger for years and never had this problem. Can this be fixed?

Javier

Answer (score 0):

Did you see if there is any JavaScript that make this mess in your blog and photographs? Or another idea, do you have free space in your Google drive that your photographs are saved?

Comment: I do have space on Google Drive. What could be the JavaScript issue that you refer to?

Comment: if a javascript cause this mess on your images....whatever....i have to see it with a link

Comment: Here is the link to the blog post with referred images: http://trazadigital.blogspot.com/2019/07/toy-region-un-modelo-para-crecer.html